# Dealing with multiple '.' in a file extension

Tags: c#, io

I have this string that contains a **filename**

```
string filename = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\filename.This.Is.An.Extension"
```

I tried using the conventional

```
string modifiedFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
```

but it only gets me:

```
modifiedFileName = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\filename.This.Is.An"
```

In order for me to get `"C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\filename"` I would have to use `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` several times, and that's just not efficient.

What better way is there to take my file name and have it return the **directory** + **filename** and no *exceptions*?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: By definition, a "file extension" is the last dot and everything after it. `System.IO.Path.GetExtension("foo.bar.baz");` returns `".baz"`. If there's some very compelling reason for you to use a different definition, write a method that returns what you want and call it `GetFileExtensionMyWay()`. As a very famous man once said, "You're a computer programmer; write some code!"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'd say just use `string.IndexOf(".")` and `string.SubString` but to be fair an extension is what comes after the last period not the first one.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you need to check your definitions here. Are you using your own definition of what a filename and extension is? If so then you need to write those methods yourself, @juharr has the right idea looking for the dot manually and using Substring. However, if you actually want the normal definition of filename and extension you already have the right code *and the right results*. **So please clarify whose definition you want to use**.

Comment: just remove all after dot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the directory and the base name:

```
var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
var baseName = Path.GetFileName(filename);
```

Strip the base name’s “extensions”:

```
var baseNameWithoutExtensions = baseName.Split(new[] {'.'}, 2)[0];
```

Recombine them:

```
var modifiedFileName = Path.Combine(directoryPath, baseNameWithoutExtensions);
```

[**demo**](https://ideone.com/cMC5QA)

Comment: You can just do `Split('.')` because it takes a `params` char array.

Comment: @juharr: Ah, thanks. I’m too used to having to specify `StringSplitArgs`. =)

Comment: You could use the overload where you tell it the max number of results `Split(new [] {'.'}, 1)` which I guess would be more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop at the first period, you will have to handle it yourself.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath) + Path.GetFileName(filepath).UpTo(".")
```

using this `string` extension:

```
public static string UpTo(this string s, string stopper) => s.Substring(0, Math.Max(0, s.IndexOf(stopper)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without built in function:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\filename.This.Is.An.Extension";
    string newString="";
    for(int i=0;i<s.Length;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='.'){
            break;
        }else{
           newString += s[i].ToString();
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(newString); //writes "C:\Users\me\Desktop\filename"
}
```